# How to change button attribute with database value in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, frameworks

I wanted to change the attribute of a button from enabled to disabled based on the data in a table database.

This is my code for the ajax, the controller and the database table that i mentioned

the column in the table that i wanted to take is commission_claim that carry 2 value. 0 and 1. 0 meaning no claim where made, and 1 there's a claim

this is the ajax part

```
$("#notify").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'affiliate/sales/notify',
        success: function(status) {

        if (status == 1) {
        showNotification("success", "Berjaya!", "Anda berjaya membuat tuntutan komisyen");
         $("#notify").attr("disabled","disabled");

        }
    }

});

  })
```

this is the action involved inside controller

public function notify()
    {

```
    $id = $this->user['id'];

    $agent = AffiliateAgents::get($id);
    if (empty($agent)) redirect('affiliate/sales/browse');

    $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);

    $agent = [
        'commission_claim' => 1

    ];

    AffiliateAgents::update($id, $agent);

    $status = AffiliateAgents::select('commission_claim')->where('id', $id)->get();

    jsonResponse(1);

    die();

    return $status;
}
```

I want the button to change based on the value in the column that i mention

Comment: use `disabled` `true` or `false` as `$("#notify").attr("disabled",true);`

Comment: the thing is when i refresh that page it will be in a state of the button being enabled. I want to like the button become enabled and disabled based on the data in the table database. so if i try to refresh it, it doesnt change back to its origin state.

Comment: then you should check status before page load and make it disabled from server side checking, it is not mandatory to use ajax at that time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#notify").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'affiliate/sales/notify',
        success: function(status) {

        if (status == 1) {
        showNotification("success", "Berjaya!", "Anda berjaya membuat tuntutan komisyen");
           $("#notify").attr("disabled", true);

        }
    }

});

  })
```

After getting the response button attribute to make disable as true.

If you want remove disable

```
$('#notify').attr("disabled", false);   
or
$('#notify').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: the thing is when i refresh that page it will be in a state of the button being enabled. I want to like the button become enabled and disabled based on the data in the table database. so if i try to refresh it, it doesnt change back to its origin state.

Comment: Then you have to check button status before page loading. keep default button status and as disable false. when you do first ajax  call then store that status in local storage and keep updating that status in the database and local storage.